# The connection is no longer usable because the server response for a previously executed statement was incorrectly formatted

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, errors, connectivity, timeout

One of our application AX2013 is connecting to our DB's in an Availability group spanning three SQL2016 nodes.
End users are getting some error in the application that always point to the same error in the eventlog:

"[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]The connection is no longer usable because the server response for a previously executed statement was incorrectly formatted."

The ax-team is looking at the DBA-team to fix this issue but we already changed the timeouts and don't see any other tasks we could do to resolve this issue.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Kind Regards

Comment: All users or some users have this issue?

Comment: "*the same error in the eventlog*" - is that the event log on the end user's machine, or on the AX server?

Comment: All users are have this problems but it occurs about 5-10 times in a day and maybe once for everyusers each day. This error can be found on the AX-server.

Comment: Is the application trying to connect directly to a replica server or connects to a listener? IS there any listener at all?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the details you've provided, it's likely this error is being caused by a network issue between the AX server and the SQL Server.  If you have a network team, it might be good to bring them in to investigate if there are packets being lost between the two servers.

Another possibility is that there is an issue with the driver AX is using to connect to SQL Server (SQL Server Native Client 11.0).  Some possible options there are to

- reinstall the driver,
- update to the most recent supported version of the driver,
- try a different driver, like MSOLEDBSQL (if that's configurable in AX, I don't know anything about that)